# How to create snap package for ubuntu snappy with already built and compiled binaries?

Tags: ubuntu, snapcraft

I'm have just started learning about snappy and how to create snap packages.
    I have built binaries for my application. I just want to create a .snap package wherein it copies my built binaries to the appropriate folders in the board file system. I have set up the snapcraft in ubuntu 15.04 . I need to create a snap wherein my snappy ubuntu core is running on Dell Edge IOT gateway. 
    Can you help me create a sample script?
    A sample of .yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Best to use the `copy` plugin. For Ubuntu Core 15.04, you could take a look at [this example](https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/1.x/examples/gopaste/snapcraft.yaml). For Ubuntu Core series 16, there's the `dump` plugin which pretty much does the same.